# How to configure Java EE 7 application to use MySQL connection pool in GlassFish

Tags: jakarta-ee, orm, glassfish-4

I have a GlassFish 4.0 server, and I've configured a MySQL connection pool and a resource name for the pool.  I can access the pool using simple JDBC.

Now I want to use JPA, and this is where I'm lost.

I believe that Glassfish already includes EclipseLink, so if I want to use that, I do not need to configure anything.  Is that correct?

However, I need to configure EclipseLink to use the pool resource.  I assume this is done in an XML file somewhere, but I'm not sure which one and where it should be.

Finally, how do I access this from within my application?  I assume I need to ask the container to `@Inject` something, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: have  a look at the Java EE tutorial. The page http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqw.html should answer all your questions. It's for EE6 but still valid in EE7.

Answer (score 0):

I've spent one night  to find the solution . After that I hated Glassfish and I am moving to the new WildFlyAS.
Look if u use the GF installed with is Netbeans than put the driver of mysql in the C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.0\glassfish\lib.
and if u use the other downloaded version zipped. u put the driver in this path D:\tools\glassfish4-install\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib\ext.
I was working on netbeans and eclipse and I was comparing the two IDEs to choose wich one I will use in the near future with JEE7. 
So , whatever the IDE that u will use u need only to choose a good placement of mysql jar driver for the GF4!
This still being amazing for me! and sure that will be for u ...just test it.
Now lets talk about JPA !
this lines will explain it for you

```
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/cv</jta-data-source>
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cv" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
```

you need the first line as I think. write your connection pool's name.
& Good luck!